# Firefox doesn't show elements but Chrome and Safari do

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

I'm using a WordPress theme and in Chrome and Safari the site looks fine.
Here is the origin theme page: http://demo.onedesigns.com/pinboard/

But in Firefox the social buttons in the upper right corner are not displayed.
I started to inspect the elements and figured out they are grayed out.
But I don't see styles that make them invisible or something like that.

What does it mean?

[image: screenshot]

Firefox 39.0, Mac 10.10.3

Comment: Looks fine to me http://puu.sh/iVsWO/6db77ca214.jpg

Comment: Most likely you have ADBLOCK with social block list on Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are blocked by the extension Adblock Plus. You can see that by the style `-moz-binding()`:

[image: Adblock Plus CSS rule]

Comment: omg, that's really strange, because 1. I use the same adblock plugin for chrome, but in chrome is still is displayed and 2. I found this style with `-moz-binding()` but when I disable the style, it was sill hidden

Comment: Yeah, it seems changing `-moz-binding()` doesn't update the layout of the page. You need to turn off Adblock Plus for that page and reload it to see the buttons. The implementation (and maybe also the default settings) of Adblock Plus in the different browsers is obviously different, therefore in Chrome you don't have this effect.